# How do i get the phone image to ignore the overflow rule

Tags: css, css-position

I want the phones in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xw7Y.png) to ignore the overflow rule set in the #section-2 and display as shown in the [phone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19N9.jpg), any tips would be very helpful.
I set the overflow to hide the outer parts of the circle pattern but it also applies to the phone image.

Ive tried adding an overflow class around the .circle class to target the [circleimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/catHQ.png) but this doesn't work.

br

```css
  // Section-2
  #section-2 {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 50vh;
    border-radius: 0 10rem 0 10rem;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow: hidden;

    // Circle image pattern

    .box {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0 10rem;
      overflow: visible;

      .circle {
        background: url(/images/bg-pattern-circles.svg);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 90rem;
        height: 90rem;
        position: absolute;
        top: -40rem;
        left: -18.5rem;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      // Phone image container
      .phone {
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        top: -5rem;

        img {
          //   position: absolute;
        }
      }
```

```html
<section id="section-2">
    

      <!-- Box containng phone image and text -->
      <div class="box">
        <!-- circular pattern -->
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="phone">
          <img src="images/illustration-phones.svg" alt="Phones" />
        </div>

        
      </div>
    </section>
```

[My current solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Setky.jpg)

Comment: I don’t see an overflow rule. What have I missed?

Comment: I've just re-uploaded the correct code, my apologies.

Comment: You can use pseudo elements, but to make it simpler to provide a full answer could you give us access to the two svgs? (i.e. give the full url). Also I don't really understand all the positionng being done by rems when the section's height and width are relative to the viewport. It won't make it very responsive. Is there a reason for using rems?

Comment: Ive added both Svgs to the question (phone and circle) to the question as well at what my current solution looks like. I generally use rems as i believe it was better for responsiveness, what do you suggest i use to adjust the position?

Comment: I can’t see any svgs.

Comment: The 'image' and 'circle image' hyperlinks. I had to convert to png as stack overflow doesn't permit SVG files for upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overflow rule is removed from the section and the background colorT he two images are removed from the main code and put behind the section using pseudo before and after elements.

That way the phones can protrude outside the section itself.

Positioning has been moved from rems to % so as to make the whole a bit more responsive - though given the aspect ratio of the phone image there needs to be some thought as to what is the intended layout on portrait devices but that is out of the scope of this question.

```css
/* Section-2 */

#section-2 {
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 0 10rem 0 10rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10vh;
  /* just so we can see the phone at the top */
}


/* Backgrounds */

#section-2::before,
#section-2::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#section-2::before {
  /* opacity: 0.9; Is this required? If so, on which of the parts of the background? */
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 10rem 0 10rem;
  background-color: #393b59;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/catHQ.png);
  background-size: 70% auto;
  background-position: -50% 80%;
}

#section-2::after {
  height: 150%;
  top: -20%;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xw7Y.png);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: 20% 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-2">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this question and provide a clear explanation, I'll start looking into pseudo selectors more as it seems quite a lot can be achieved with them.